# how to hide list when user select item from list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

could you please tell me how to hide list when user select item from list .Actually when user type anything on text field it show a list , when user select any row from the list it set value on text field .But that time I need to hide my list .So I take one boolean variable  **$scope.islisthide=false;** using that value I need to hide or show list .Please press **"a"** than select value from list .I already use **ng-show** but how to add condition in that .

```
<div class="listcontainer" ng-show="SEARCH.stationCode" >
    <li ng-click="rowclick(station)" class="item" ng-repeat="station in data.data | filter:SEARCH.stationCode :startsWith">{{station.stationName+"-("+station.stationCode+")"}}</li>
</div> 

$scope.rowclick = function(station) {
    $scope.SEARCH.stationCode=station.stationCode;
    //  $scope.$apply();
}
```

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGYPWj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a flag to indicate whether a selection has been made. Here's an example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPwjvN

I am using a flag called `selected`